# Cannot update Bokeh chart with CheckboxGroup

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to make interactive bokeh line charts. I use CheckboxGroup widget to update the charts. However, the charts won't update.

```
d={'created':['02/01/2019 00:00:00','03/01/2019 00:00:00','04/01/2019 00:00:00','05/01/2019 00:00:00','06/01/2019 00:00:00','07/01/2019 00:00:00'],
   'aaa': [5, 4, 10, 7, 5, 5], 
   'bbb':[0,10,2,9,8,4],
   'ccc':[10,12,14,14,5,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['created']=pd.to_datetime(df['created'])
df.set_index('created', inplace=True)

plot=figure(plot_width=700,
            plot_height=500,
            x_axis_type='datetime',
            title='lines')

src=ColumnDataSource(df)

products=sorted(list(src.data.keys())[1:])

product_selection=CheckboxGroup(labels=products, active =[0,1])


def make_dataset(initial_dataframe, columns_to_keep):
    df=initial_dataframe[columns_to_keep].copy()
    src=ColumnDataSource(df)
    return src

for i  in product_selection.active:
    plot.line(x='created', y=product_selection.labels[i], source=src)


def update(attr, old, new):
    prods=[product_selection.labels[i] for i in product_selection.active]
    src=make_dataset(df,prods)

product_selection.on_change('active', update)


layout=row(plot,product_selection)


curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Please help me to correct my code.

Comment: Do you want to show / hide the lines depending on checkbox selection? Do you know that you can achieve the same by using a `Legend`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show / hide the lines at checkbox selection then you could do it this way by using `visibility` attribute of a glyph (run the code with `bokeh serve --show app.py`):

```
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, ColumnDataSource, Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
import pandas as pd

d={'created':['02/01/2019 00:00:00','03/01/2019 00:00:00','04/01/2019 00:00:00','05/01/2019 00:00:00','06/01/2019 00:00:00','07/01/2019 00:00:00'],
   'aaa': [5, 4, 10, 7, 5, 5], 
   'bbb': [0, 10, 2, 9, 8, 4],
   'ccc': [10, 12, 14, 14, 5, 7]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['created']=pd.to_datetime(df['created'])
df.set_index('created', inplace=True)

plot=figure(plot_width=700,
            plot_height=500,
            x_axis_type='datetime',
            title='lines')

src=ColumnDataSource(df)
products=sorted(list(src.data.keys())[1:])
product_selection=CheckboxGroup(labels=products, active =[0,1])

lines = []
for i, column  in enumerate(df.columns.tolist()):
    line = plot.line(x='created', y=column, source=src)
    line.visible = i in product_selection.active
    lines.append(line)

def update(attr, old, new):
    for i, renderer in enumerate(lines):
        if i in product_selection.active:
            renderer.visible = True
        else:
            renderer.visible = False

product_selection.on_change('active', update)
curdoc().add_root(Row(plot,product_selection))
```

Result:
[image]